# BroadCast & Hide Activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, hide, broadcast

How can an application in the background without any activity performed.
For example, an application I wrote that I'm no activity Broadcast software is running.
I wrote software without activity, but when I run the software does not run broadcast will be an activity for the first run.

Because of my lack of activity is not shown to the user application.
Do you have an idea for it to be displayed to the user?

Comment: 1. do some research (similar questions was asked here bazillion times)... but 2. there is no way to broadcast get called without any activity in app - user have to run your app at least once to "activate" broadcast recivers ... 2. question is not clear ... you wana service running all the time(google for that) ... or just recivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) for Android 3.1:

> Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of
>   applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of
>   controlling their launch from background processes and other
>   applications.

And

> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but
>   are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user
>   (in Manage Applications).

You should include an Activity that can be launched by the user, otherwise your app will never come out of this stopped state.